# Can you please help me model this curve?

Tags: mathematical-modeling, data-analysis

I have no idea how to model this curve. Can someone please help?

[image]

Comment: The image isn't even complete. $$\quad$$ What do you want exactly? A function that goes through the red squares?

Comment: Oops! I put the complete image up now.
I'm not too sure. I'm completely lost when it comes to this modeling thing. I guess a function that goes through the red squares would be what I'm looking for, yes.

Comment: Look into polynomial interpolation. One possibility is the [Lagrange Polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial). Wolfram Alpha gives [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=interpolating+polynomial+%7B%281%2C1%29%2C+%282%2C1%29%2C+%283%2C3%29%2C+%284%2C5%29%2C+%285%2C5%29%2C+%286%2C4%29%2C+%287%2C4%29%2C+%288%2C9%29%2C+%289%2C11%29%2C+%2810%2C+12%29%2C+%2811%2C5%29%2C+%2812%2C3%29%7D) polynomial as a possible model for that function.

Comment: Thank you so much. The graph looks good, except at between the first and second points, and the eleventh and twelveth points, the curve (http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=interpolating+polynomial+%7B%281%2C0.986%29%2C+%282%2C1.02%29%2C+%283%2C2.914%29%2C+%284%2C5.372%29%2C+%285%2C4.744%29%2C+%286%2C3.695%29%2C+%287%2C4.018%29%2C+%288%2C8.7033%29%2C+%289%2C10.67%29%2C+%2810%2C+12.34925%29%2C+%2811%2C5.1%29%2C+%2812%2C3.058%29%7D) goes up and down dramatically, which doesn't make logical sense to fit the situation I want to model. Does this mean that I can't use polynomial interpolation?

Comment: No, not at all. It means the lagrange polynomial won't help (directly) with this. There are other ways to interpolate, though. Alas I don't know much about this. Hopefully someone else can help you with. In spite of all this, you can (try to) use a little trick which is to add points between the points which are causing you trouble. The more, the merrier.

Comment: Okay, thank you so much for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: So six turning points implies degree at least $7$ (so the derivative has degree at least $6$). The idea that the polynomial is going down at the left and up at the right implies an odd degree polynomial with positive leading coefficient.

Answer (score 0):

This is a positive, 7th degreee polynomial that starts at about y = 2. It doesn't cross the x-axis, or else I would be able to give roots. However, a 7th degree polynomial would produce the best-fit curve and that is what you need.